# Displaying a javascript var in html body

Tags: javascript, html, variables, calculator, calculated-field

I am looking for a way to call a javascript variable "o" in the body of an html calculator. I can't understand why this isn't working. Please help, thank you!

```js
function calc() {
    var i = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var p = document.getElementById("percent").value;
    var o = (i / 100) * p;

}

function GetTotal() {
    document.getElementById('answer').style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:calc()">
    Input: <input type="text" id="input" /><br />
    Percent: <input type="text" id="percent" value="10" />%<br />

    <input type="button" style="color:#000;" name="Get Total" value="Get Total" onclick="GetTotal()" />

    <div id="answer" style="display:none;"> Total:
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write(o) </script>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esme,

Your document.write(o)  snippet is executed right after page load. And that time 'o' variable is not defined. After click on the button, you make your div visible but don't update the result. Here is a possible suggestion to your problem:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Calculator</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function calc() {
  var i = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var p = document.getElementById("percent").value;
  return (i/100) * p;
}

function GetTotal() {
   document.getElementById('answer').style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById('answer_value').innerText = calc();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
Input: <input type="text" id="input"/><br />
Percent: <input type="text" id="percent" value="10"/>%<br />

<input type="button" style="color:#000;" name="Get Total" value="Get Total" onclick="GetTotal()" />

<div id="answer" style="display:none;"> Total: <span id="answer_value"></span> </div>
      
</form>


</body>
</html>
```